# Running hidden tor service behind vpn, is it possible?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, tor

Just wondering if one would have a tor hidden service running on a dedicated server behind a VPN would then still the in and outbound content both go and come in trough the VPN without revealing the real users IP address that is connected to the VPN provider?
Service is up and running and wondering if the outbound connection content that the server is sending is routed through the VPN provider.
And if the inbound content to the server is then also running through the vpn.

Setup = Dedicated Server Running VM Linux x Running Tor Service X OpenVPN on a tomato router => Web

Look forward to opinions and more.

Thanks :)